# Microsoft.Toolkit.Services.OneDrive.OneDriveService Saved Login

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm using `Microsoft.Toolkit.Services 3.0.0` library for connecting to `OneDrive`.

My code to authenticate user is:

```
        if(OneDriveService.Instance.Initialize(App.ClientId, 
          new string[] { MicrosoftGraphScope.FilesReadWrite }, null, null))
        {
            if (!await OneDriveService.Instance.LoginAsync())
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to sign in");
            }

        // Code to access OneDrive here
        }
```

I'm able to login to my `OneDrive` account, but the problem is it's asking me to loggin every time I want to access `OneDrive`, before using this library I'm using `Microsoft.OneDriveSDK` which don't show any login after user login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [official code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit//tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/OneDrive%20Service) to test login. But I can not reproduce your issue. In my side, it could save the login info after login success. It will automatically login next time.

Please refer [OneDrive Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/services/onedrive) and use code sample to test your application id then exclude other issue.

**Update**

If your Visual Studio reinstall your app during debug, you could check project `Debug` option. Right click your project->Properties->Debug uncheck **Uninstall and then re-install...** option. You could solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I just found what cause this behavior, Visual Studio is reinstall my apps when debugging and running test.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that this not `library` fault, but `Visual Studio` is `reinstall` my apps almost every time I start the my apps in Visual Studio (for the good reason).

I try reopen my apps without rebuilding in Visual Studio, and work as I expected, the login is automatically after successful one.